# sending mail using php with a proper format

Tags: php, html

I send mail from the registered form in a site using php. Mail also sent successfully. But the mail is showing all the html codes. It does not shows properly like:

```
Name : xxxxxx
Age  : 24
Email: example@example.com
```

May I know how to sending the mail as above. The current coding I am using is as below:

```
<?php
$solvation = "<html>" . $_POST['solvation'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$to = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['message'];
$message = '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>' .
  '<head>' .
  '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html">' .
  '<title>Email notification</title>' .
  '</head>' .
  '<body>' .
  '<div id="outer" style="width: 80%;margin: 0 auto;margin-top: 10px;">' .
  '<div id="inner" style="width: 78%;margin: 0 auto;background-color: #fff;font-family: Open Sans,Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 1.4em;color: #444;margin-top: 10px;">' .
  '<p> Solvation        :' . $solvation . '</p>' .
  '<p> Name         :' . $name . '</p>' .
  '<p> Email            :' . $email . '</p>' .
  '<p> Message      :' . $msg . '</p>' .
  '</div>' .
  '</div>' .
  '<div id="footer" style="width: 80%;height: 40px;margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;padding: 10px;font-family: Verdena;background-color: #E2E2E2;">' .
  '</div>' .
  '</body>' .
  '</html>';
//$headers   = $solvation."\n".$name."\n".$email."\n".$message."\n";
$headers = 'From: garunkumar41@gmail.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: garunkumar41@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($solvation, $name, $to, $message, $headers);
?>
```

I want to send the email like above.. Can I get help?

Comment: May be try with "$headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"" instead of "$headers.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"".

Comment: @chandresh_cool I don't see any difference.

Comment: You can also use **PHPMailer** Which allow you to send HTML Mail with Attachments too

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it. But its not working.@chandresh_cool

Comment: he said, Content_type instead Content_Type.... In this, T is caps in my case for Type, he said use small case @Rene Korss

Comment: @ArunkumarG Ok, now I see it. Thanks. But there shouldn't be difference in this.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Yes you are correct @Rene Korss

Comment: Ok I will follow in future @JohnSaunders

Comment: This issue has been solved. Wishes to all of you whom tried to help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: change  `$solvation` and  `$message` as below

```
$solvation = $_POST['solvation'];    
 $message   = '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
                                <head>
                                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html">
                                <title>Email notification</title>
                                </head>
                                <body>
                                <div id="outer" style="width: 80%;margin: 0 auto;margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div id="inner" style="width: 78%;margin: 0 auto;background-color: #fff;font-family: Open Sans,Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 1.4em;color: #444;margin-top: 10px;">
                                <p> Solvation      :'.$solvation.'</p> 
                                <p> Name           :'.$name.'</p>
                                <p> Email          :'.$email.'</p>
                                <p> Message        :'.$msg.'</p>
                                </div>  
                                </div>
                                <div id="footer" style="width: 80%;height: 40px;margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;padding: 10px;font-family: Verdena;background-color: #E2E2E2;">
                               </div>
                                </body> 
                                </html>';
```

**EDIT:**  try by changing

this

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

to

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

also check whether you have defined `$email` in your PHP code

Comment: Again It shows the same html codes in the mail. Not in the specified format.

Comment: @Arunkumar G: ok, if your mail is sending successfully then i will suggest try first by sending simple html e.g. shown here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp . And do you have `$email`  this variable defined somewhere in your php? As I can not see in your question code?

Comment: @Arunkumar G: check my EDIT from the answer also.

Comment: @ Kiran: It works perfectly. Very Happy. Wishes for your help.

Comment: @ Arunkumar G: Glad that your problem is solved. please mention how did you solved your answer with the help of any answer here or any other way(as your own answer). So that whoever will face this similar problem they will have the solution here.

Comment: @ Arunkumar G: Glad that my answer helped you. :) you forgot - Click to accept then. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$solvation = "<html>".$_POST['solvation'];
```

with

```
$solvation = $_POST['solvation'];
```

Otherwise you would have double `html` starting tags and therefore invalid HTML, which results in sending it like plain text.

And your `mail` function has wrong argument order. It should be

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I don't know what variable `$solvation` contains, so just replace `$subject` with proper value.

Answer (score 0):

### Proposed Answer

Ok, here is your fixed code, pay attention that this is a bad way for sending mail since you need sanitize your inputs. In other way, my code works but you need implement sanitize inputs by using regex. If you want know why your code isn't working:

1) you have some terminators wrong;

2) you have bad values in var;

3) you have values that are not sent with your code;

4) you concatenated your html markup code (see below):

```
'<title>Email notification</title>' .
'</head>'
```

in other words you sent as below:

```
<title>Email notification</title></head>
```

it means that your html code will be sent in one single line and this is bad for standard html mail format, each tag should be sent with a carriage return, you can write your markup as below:

```
$message =
'<title>Email notification</title>
</head>
etc...';
```

So you will respect the natural carriage return in each html tag...

For future references: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3785

Copy the code below and save as mail.php and give a try

**mail.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<title>Email Notification</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
Solvation:<br><input type="text" name="solvation" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['solvation']) ? $_POST['solvation']  : ''; ?>"><br><br>
Name:<br><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name']  : ''; ?>"><br><br>
To:<br><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email']  : ''; ?>"><br><br>
Message:<br><textarea name="message"><?php echo isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message']  : ''; ?></textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"><br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if (!defined('PHP_EOL')) {
  if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'WIN')) {
    define('PHP_EOL',"\r\n");
  } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'MAC')) {
    define('PHP_EOL',"\r");
  } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'DAR')) {
    define('PHP_EOL',"\n");
  } else {
    define('PHP_EOL',"\n");
  }
}
$solvation = isset($_POST['solvation']) ? $_POST['solvation']  : '';
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name']  : '';
$to = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email']  : '';
$msg = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message']  : '';
$message =
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Email notification</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer" style="width: 80%;margin: 0 auto;margin-top: 10px;">
<div id="inner" style="width: 78%;margin: 0 auto;background-color: #fff;font-family: Open Sans,Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 1.4em;color: #444;margin-top: 10px;">
<p>Solvation: ' . $solvation . '</p>
<p>Name: ' . $name . '</p>
<p>Email: ' . $to . '</p>
<p>Message: ' . $msg . '</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer" style="width: 80%;height: 40px;margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;padding: 10px;font-family: Verdena;background-color: #E2E2E2;">
</div>
</body>
</html>';
// Basilar Settings
$mail_boundary = "=_NextPart_" . md5(uniqid(time()));  // Create a Boundary
$headers = "From: garunkumar41@gmail.com <garunkumar41@gmail.com>" . PHP_EOL;  // From Header
$headers .= "Reply-To: garunkumar41@gmail.com <garunkumar41@gmail.com>" . PHP_EOL;  // Reply-To Header
$headers .= "Return-Path: <garunkumar41@gmail.com>" . PHP_EOL;  // Return-Path Header
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;  // Mime Version
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;" . PHP_EOL . "  boundary=\"$mail_boundary\"" . PHP_EOL;  // Header MultiPart
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP Mailer Script 1.0";  // Name of the Php App
$name = html_entity_decode($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1');  // HTML converted in ascii
$solvation = html_entity_decode($solvation, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1');  // HTML converted in ascii
$msgplus = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;  // Multipart Message
// TEXT Message
$msgplus .= "--$mail_boundary" . PHP_EOL;
$msgplus .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . PHP_EOL;
$msgplus .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msgplus .= "Text Begins Here ->" . strip_tags(html_entity_decode($msg, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1')) . "<- Text Ends Here";
// HTML Message
$msgplus .= PHP_EOL . "--$mail_boundary" . PHP_EOL;
$msgplus .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . PHP_EOL;
$msgplus .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msgplus .= $message;
// Sending Message
$msgplus .= PHP_EOL . "--$mail_boundary--" . PHP_EOL;  // Final Boundary multipart/alternative
@ini_set("sendmail_from", "garunkumar41@gmail.com");  // Used only under Windows
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $ok = @mail($to, $solvation, $msgplus, $headers, "-fgarunkumar41@gmail.com");
  if ($ok) {
    exit("Mail Sent! Thanks!");
  } else {
    exit("Mail Not Sent! Sorry!");
  }
} else {
  echo "Ready to Send Your Mail";
}
?>
```

Comment: Again it sends the same HTML tags that, what we give inside the single quotes( '   ' ) in the $ message. I does not returns the proper format.

Comment: Have you tried my code? If yes check in your web mail account settings and check 'wanted mail format', maybe is set to plain text...

Comment: Give a try to my code please, do not try to make working your since I suspect has more problems... get mine and try...

Comment: I'm happy for you Arunkumar :) Your issue is solved :)

Comment: Also I'm very kind for your help too... @ Alessandro